# Prototyping Built-In Modules in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype-programming

I've been trying to add some convenience functions to Node's file system module (mainly because it lacks some common sense things), but every time I begin `fs.prototype.myfunc =` in the repl, Node complains that I am trying to set a property of an undefined variable. Is it really true that you cannot access Node's built-in module prototypes from the outside? If so, does anyone know a feasible workaround to extend Node's built-in modules?

Just to note: I did require fs before trying to prototype it!

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.prototype.myfunc = function() {}; //TypeError thrown here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you get back in response to a require('') depends upon the particular module. Some modules do this:

```
module.exports = function() {}
```

in that case, the value returned would be function and so would have a prototype you could attach things to.

Other modules just set values on the already existing exports.module object. E.g:

```
module.exports.someFunc = function(){}
```

where module.exports is essentially just:

```
module.exports = {}
```

In the case of the fs module they do the latter:

```
var fs = exports;

....

fs.readFileSync = function(path, encoding) {
```

So you get the error you do since the object returned isn't a function. You'd get the same error if you did this:

```
var x = {};

x.prototype.myfunc = function(){}
```

Note you can just do:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.myFunc = function(){}
```

Comment: Of course! A quick test shows you are absolutely right (and that I apparently don't know as much about JS as I thought). Thank you for pointing this out & explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example  of how to do it:

https://github.com/mikeal/node-utils/blob/master/file/lib/main.js

Answer (score 1):

There might be a workaround, but node is sending you a message by not letting you monkey patch its modules. Doing `require('fs-monkeypatch')` to get extra functions in `require('fs')` is confusing. Just add your functions outside of the fs module.

Comment: Point taken. Kind of disappointing that you can't just extend the module (read: not replacing current functions with evil ones), but I'm sure it was done for a reason. I'll probably just go with your suggestion and add the functions to the file where I need them. Thanks for the input!